# Strange javac Tab Completion for Classpath

Tags: bash, javac, tab-completion, bash-completion

The javac command has strange tab completion with `-cp` and `-classpath`. I was under the impression `-cp` was an alias for `-classpath`. However, when I press tab after the `-classpath` flag, I get `.jar` files as expected. When I press tab with `-classpath` I get:

```
javac -classpath <tab>
javac -classpath lib/ <tab>
javac -classpath lib/test.jar
```

and

```
javac -classpath .: <tab>
javac -classpath .:lib/ <tab>
javac -classpath .:lib/test.jar
```

Alternatively, with `-cp`

```
javac -cp <tab>
javac -cp lib/ <tab>
javac -cp lib/
```

and

```
javac -cp .: <tab>
javac -cp .:
```

I'm using bash in ubuntu 16.04 and javac 1.8.0_111 if that's relevant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This functionality is implemented by the `bash-completion` package.  You can find the code for the relevant function like so:

```
$ complete -p javac
complete -F _javac javac  # the function `_javac' is used to complete the command `javac'
$ declare -f _javac .     # this will print the function code
```

There you'll see that the relevant code is:

```
case $prev in
    ...
    -classpath|-bootclasspath|-sourcepath|-extdirs)
    ...
```

So if you want, you can take the whole definition of `_javac()` from the `declare -f` command, modify it to include `-cp` in that `case` statement, and append it to the *end* of your bash init file (`.bashrc` or `.bash_profile`, etc).  Then, when you start a new shell, the new `_javac()` will be used to complete `javac` commands.

Also, the code for the latest release is also viewable on [github](https://github.com/scop/bash-completion/blob/619fb1f86ece68ea56e0e5c30c030376c1f8a07f/completions/java#L294).  Other command completions defined there (`java`, `javadoc`) understand the short-hand flags so I'm sure a pull request with a fix for this issue would be welcome.

---

<sup>**Update:** This is now [fixed](https://github.com/scop/bash-completion/issues/109) in the source.</sup>